# How to get specific element in Javascript

Tags: jquery, ajax, html

When I send the AJAX request, if it success it returning a values. For example

```
$('#content').load(url, function (info) {

})
```

In this code `info` is returning the HTML page source.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US" dir="ltr" autopagermatchedrules="1">
<head>
<body class="single single-post postid-1 single-format-standard logged-in admin-bar single-author singular two-column right-sidebar" linkifying="true">
</html>
```

How can I get the body class name.

Answer (score 5):

This should do it.

```
$('#content').load(url, function (info) {
    var classes = $(info).find('body').attr('class');
});
```

Comment: Ok.. for me its not working... pls check the url [link](http://jsfiddle.net/5qQwS)

Comment: @Mifas I think it has to do with all the extra elements. Try writing it to an `iframe` and then searching or if you're desperate use a regular expression.

Comment: @alex can u  please tell me how can i do this in regular expression